# Error trying install Stratos Message Broker as a feature in WSO2 ESB 4.9

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

WSO2 Message Broker v3.1 documentation suggests that it is possible to use Message Broker as an ESB Feature, called "Stratos Message Broker - Dashboard UI Features": [from here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Integrating+WSO2+ESB)

I am trying to install the MB as a Feature on the latest WSO2 ESB version (v4.9), just as it came.

To do that I'm using the latest P2 Repository:
[from here](http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/)

After selecting "Stratos Message Broker - Dashboard UI Features" v 3.1, I am getting the following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

Software being installed: 
 WSO2 Stratos Message Broker - Dashboard UI Features 3.1.0 (org.wso2.stratos.mb.dashboard.ui.feature.group 3.1.0) 
Software currently installed: 
 WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 4.4.1) 

Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
 WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar 4.4.1) 
 WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.2 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar 4.4.2) 
 WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.3 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar 4.4.3) 
 WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.4 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar 4.4.4) 

Cannot satisfy dependency: 
 From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 4.4.1) 
 To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar [4.4.1] 

Cannot satisfy dependency: 
 From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.3 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 4.4.3) 
 To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar [4.4.3] 

Cannot satisfy dependency: 
 From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.4 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 4.4.4) 
 To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar [4.4.4] 

Cannot satisfy dependency: 
 From: WSO2 Stratos Message Broker - Dashboard UI Features 3.1.0 (org.wso2.stratos.mb.dashboard.ui.feature.group 3.1.0) 
 To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group [4.4.3,4.5.0)
```

**Does it mean that it's not possible to use the latest version of MB as an ESB Feature? I tried others, no success..**

Repo: WSO2 Carbon 4.2.0 (Turing) - MB version: 2.2.0 - Error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. 
Software being installed: 
 WSO2 Stratos Message Broker - Dashboard UI Features 2.2.0 (org.wso2.stratos.mb.dashboard.ui.feature.group 2.2.0) 

Software currently installed:
 WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 4.4.1) 

Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
 WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar 4.2.0) 
 WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar 4.4.1) 

Cannot satisfy dependency: 
 From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 4.2.0) 
 To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar [4.2.0] 
Cannot satisfy dependency: 
 From: WSO2 Carbon - Carbon UI Feature 4.4.1 (org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group 4.4.1) 
 To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.jar [4.4.1] 
Cannot satisfy dependency: 
 From: WSO2 Stratos Message Broker - Dashboard UI Features 2.2.0 (org.wso2.stratos.mb.dashboard.ui.feature.group 2.2.0) 
 To: org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group [4.2.0,4.3.0)
```

Repo: WSO2 Carbon 4.1.7 - MB version: 2.1.1 - Error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found. 
Software being installed: 
 WSO2 Stratos Message Broker - Dashboard UI Features 2.1.1 (org.wso2.stratos.mb.dashboard.ui.feature.group 2.1.1) 

Missing requirement: 
 WSO2 Stratos Message Broker - Dashboard UI Features 2.1.1 (org.wso2.stratos.mb.dashboard.ui.feature.group 2.1.1) 
 requires 'org.wso2.carbon.core.ui.feature.group [4.1.0,4.2.0)' but it could not be found
```

**Any suggestion?**
**Does anyone already uses MB as an ESB feature? Which version?**

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Successful install using the new version of **WSO2 ESB 5.0**.

Using [wilkes repo](http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/) and selecting "Stratos Message Broker - Dashboard UI Features version 3.1.0".

Actually to make it work I did: a search in my old MB, looking for features there (MB 3.1 alone) that don't exist here (ESB 5.0). That's the list:

- Feature - Andes
- Feature - Messaging Metrics
- Metrics Group
- Registry Content Search
- Remote user management
- Remote user management Client
- Remote user management Server
- SOAP Tracer
- Stratos Message Broker - Dashboard UI Features

Then I had to edit `master-datasources.xml` file, to add `WSO2MBStoreDB` datasource configuration.

And after that, just install the features from the list above.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried and got the same error. It looks like a bug in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0. Hence reported a jira: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4753